# Is there a way to allow certain classes to access private properties of certain other classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scope, encapsulation, private-members

I have 2 classes that I want to be able to access each others properties, but I don't want those properties accessed from anywhere else. Is there a way to do this? Is the only way to accomplish this through subclassing? Is there no way to establish a "special" relationship between two classes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand your question, you effectively want class A and class B, which are unrelated by inheritance, to be aware of more innards than are publicly advertised?

Say A has a property called `innardsForB` that only instances of B should access. You can use class extensions to declare the non-public interface to A.

---

**A.h**

```
@interface A:NSObject
... regular class goop here ...
@end
```

---

**A-Private.h**

```
@interface A()
@property(nonatomic, strong) Innards *innardsForB;
@end
```

---

**A.m**

```
#import "A.h"
#import "A-Private.h"

@implementation A
// because "A-Private.h" is #import'd, `innardsForB` will be automatically @synthesized
...
@end
```

---

**B.m**

```
#import "B.h"
#import "A-Private.h"

@implementation B
...
- (void)someMethod
{
     A *a = [self someASomewhere];
     a.innardsForB = [[Innards alloc] initForMeaning:@(42)];
}
```

Comment: In this example A-Private.h is the class extension?

Comment: Correct; `@interface A()` is the class extension. It means "extend class A such that it has this additional set of declarations". As long as that extension is visible to the compiler when the `@implementation` is compiled, then all of the declarations in the extension behave just like they were declared in the class's `@interface`.

Answer (score 3):

Protocols are designed for that purpose. You cannot stop 3rd party classes from implementing or using a protocol. Methods within these are public but not nessecarily part of the public interface.

Answer (score 1):

Communication between objects:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html

Answer (score -1):

I you want that classA access classB's properties and classC does't you simply déclare a reference of classA in ClassB and don't declare it in ClassB.

Example :

```
@interface ClassA
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label1;
@end

#import "ClassB.h"
#import "ClassA.h"  // To access public properties and all methods declared in ClassA.h

@implementation ClassB 

ClassA *classA = ....;
classA.label1.text = ...;

@end
```

From this example, ClassB can access all public(déclared in CalssA.h) proerties and methods of ClassA.

You can use delegate also to do this.

Comment: This is information duplication that leads to fragility across your codebase.  You now have to remember to always search your code for all re-declarations of every property in case it has been duplicated elsewhere.

Answer (score -8):

On obj-c properties are protected. That means you can only accede properties by inheritance.

```
@interface A : NSObject{
    NSObject* prop;
}
@end

@implementation A
@end

@interface B : A
@end

@implementation B
- (void)protected{
    self->prop; // yep
}
@end

@interface XXX : NSObject
@end

@implementation XXX

- (void)test{
    A* a = [[A alloc] init];
    a->prop; // wrong, will not compile
}

@end
```

If you want to access hidden properties via method, you can use simply category hidden in implementation, or bridge. But there is no way to establish a "special" relationship between two classes. But you can enforce this relationship with your code design.

Comment: There are no properties in your code and the use of `->` breaks encapsulation.

Comment: `prop` is an instance variable, which is quite a bit different from a property which has a very specific meaning in ObjC.   Using a category to access "hidden" functionality in another class is a poor suggestion; class extensions were created exactly to solve this problem as I outlined in my answer and it serves to create exactly such a "special" relationship.

Comment: @MrBonjour you should learn who bbum is. Then you will understand the hilarity of your comment. :)

Comment: @bbum is my favorite in stackoverflow, but who is :)?

Comment: bbum, we are talking the same things in different manner. Properties are data structure inside class, aka "instance variable", and yeah @properties on obj-c means you can access property via method. But on design "@properties" are methods, even if they are called properties! Then if you call an hidden method from client side, and u know this method is valid, then who care. use performSelector, or an hidden category or whatever. But it's always related to design. Not language specific. You can't make "friend" like on C++ or whatever magic inside compiler. this is what this topic was about. sad

Comment: Actually, `@property` also defines -- synthesizes -- the storage that backs the setter/getter.   Thus, properties in Obj-C are a complete replacement for ivars (on all but the legacy runtime).   Suggesting that calling a hidden method either directly or via `performSelector:` is an exceptionally bad idea outside of debugging or sheer desperation.

Comment: @samir, bbum works for Apple. "Bill Bumgarner is an Engineering Manager at Apple. He manages the runtime technologies team that is responsible for Objective-C and related technologies."

source: http://www.newtonacademy.org/resources/ios-rockstars

I'm pretty sure he know's what a property is.

Comment: bbum, you know i agree with you. So yeah i was wrong, hope that make you happy

Comment: @MrBonjour please don't take any of this personally! Given all the downvotes and the comments, it can feel like we're ganging up on you, and I'm sorry if you feel that way.  Every now and then someone makes a really hilarious (and usually wrong) comment on SO, and people find out about it and come comment on it (because it's funny!).

Comment: @MrBonjour  No worries -- I do this for two reasons; helping folks requires that I gain a deeper understanding & I can capture the sticking points such that the tools will improve in the future to try an eliminate said sticking points.   Successful developers makes me happy.

Comment: ok, thx Dave. Yeah i must admit, it was funny. And yeah, i have been a little too harsh and a little too wrong. So i find myself a kind of stupid. By the way yourfriendzak, will definitively not use what i was suggesting, nor blum either.

Comment: It turned into a bit of a pile-on.  Sorry about that.